# Search action using linq predicate. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering how to implement search functionality?

Let's see how do I imagine about it. I will use `employee` model for the example. So `employee` holds rather standard properties: 'Id', `EmployeeId`, `Name`, `Birthday`.

My `Repository` object holds a method like:

```
IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate);
```

So then `Search` (belongs to `EmployeeController`) action would look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Search(Guid Id, Guid EmployeeId, String Name, DateTime birthday)
{
    // call repository.get(x => x.Name == Name && x.Id == Id ... );
}
```

The `Search` view would then hold a form with *textboxes* corresponding to search criterias/action parameters.

But there the searching ability is coupled to the model/controller. So I would need to create similar action per controller.

How to make it in some better manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can use ViewModel while passing your arguments to your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Search(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
  //logic
}
```

2 - For a generic search functionality, you can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the predicate code is repeated across all calls to the repository, then you should either make that part of the repository, by creating a specific `EmployeeRepository`, that can either derive from your generic repository, or use it via composition:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : GenericRepository<Employee>
{
   public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesBySearch(string id, string name...)
   {
     return this.Get(x => x.Name == name && ...);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could consider the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). This separates the concern of selecting objects from the concern of which objects to select. There is an example with NHibernate [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/nhibernate-3-using-linq-specifications-data-access-layer).

Comment: Nope. Not at all. Thing is not in predicate repetitions (it's obviously that predicates would be diffrerent). The thing is in action repetition across controllers. I was wondering maybe I could abstract away the `Search` functionality?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, are you saying you have a similar search form per type of entity on each view? or are you saying you have one search form that needs to be used across multiple views, like in a header for example?

Comment: For now I have neither. But your last option is what I want. And I don't want to change repository class. But I'm gonna consider what you've adviced.